# Как совместить в запросе union и left join, чтобы получить то, что нужно?

Tags: mysql

Фишка в чем. У меня на сайте есть подписка на комментарии пользователей. То есть юзер может написать сообщение и поставить галочку "подписка" и ему будет сообщено, когда ему ответят. Есть 3 таблицы: сами комментарии, подписки (они связываются с юзером и номером комментария) и таблица со статусами комментариев (туда запись идет, если этот пользователь видел этот комментарий).

В итоге, чтобы пользователю показывать список подписок с удобной колонкой "количество непрочитанных", по которой таблица и сортируется, приходится делать трехэтажный join. Но это еще ничего.

Назрела необходимость дополнить этот запрос еще данными. Дело в том, что пользователи еще и пишут свои материалы, которые другие пользователи комментируют. Соответственно, все то же самое: появляется комментарий, если нет записи о том, что автор материала видел этот комментарий, ему должно быть сообщено. То есть по сути свой материал = это все равно что подписка на него.

Так вот, для пользователей оптимален был бы вариант, когда все нужные данные были бы в одной таблице.

То есть в данный момент логически запрос выглядит так:

```
SELECT данные, COUNT(количество комментариев) as count1, COUNT(количество просмотренных комментариев) as count2, (COUNT(количество комментариев) - COUNT(количество просмотренных комментариев)) as summ FROM таблица-подписка-на-комментарии
LEFT JOIN таблица-комментариев ON соответствие
LEFT JOIN таблица-просмотров ON соответствие
GROUP BY таблица-подписка-на-комментарии.id
```

И, собственно, есть такая команда, как UNION, которой я толком никогда не пользовалась. Она дает возможность в том числе сделать выборку такого вида:

```
(SELECT i, c FROM t1 ORDER BY i DESC) UNION (SELECT i, d FROM t2 ORDER BY i)
```

и в итоге (как пишут в мануале) мы получим данные из обеих таблиц одна за другой. Так вот, в чем, собственно, вопрос. Можно ли как-то эти 2 вещи объединить? То есть у меня есть таблица "таблица-подписка-на-комментарии" и таблица с материалами пользователей. Мне нужно что-то вроде

```
(SELECT данные FROM таблица-подписка-на-комментарии ORDER BY i DESC) UNION (SELECT данные FROM таблица-материалов WHERE autor = 1 ORDER BY i)
```

И ко всему этому в целом LEFT JOIN-ить остальные таблицы. Такое вообще возможно? Или это просто бредни моей задолбанной головы?

Comment: Все, нашла вариант тут: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440808/mysql-union-of-a-left-join-with-a-right-join



select a.id, t1.column_1, t2.column_2
from (
    select id from t1
    union 
    select id from t2
) a
left outer join t1 on a.id = t1.id
left outer join t2 on a.id = t2.id


Работает

Comment: можно. `select from (select... union select...) as псевдоним join....`

Answer (score 2):

*Ответ из комментариев от автора вопроса*

```
SELECT
  a.id,
  t1.column_1,
  t2.column_2
FROM
  ( select id from t1 union select id from t2 ) a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  t1
ON
  a.id = t1.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  t2
ON
  a.id = t2.id
```